Symfony 5: 404 error page routing for different themes of a multi-site repo
For my main site, https://hb.test/_error/404 works fine.
However, for the other site https://hart.test/_error/404 under the same repo,
Symfony Profiler shows that themes/hb/templates/bundles/TwigBundle/Exception/error404.html.twig was rendered instead of themes/hart/templates/bundles/TwigBundle/Exception/error404.html.twig.
routing_dev.yml:
_errors:
    resource: '@FrameworkBundle/Resources/config/routing/errors.xml'
    prefix: /_error

What can I do to have the hart folder's error404.html.twig template to be rendered?
I have verified the template path and tried php bin/console cache:clear --env=dev. Any pointers would be much appreciated!
